# How to echo encoded url image through <img src>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

Let's say I have a url of an image link location that doesn't have an extension (.jpg) but when I go to the url it shows me that the corresponding link is an image? How would echo this url in php?

For example the recaptcha image from recaptcha.net it encodes the string with a public key. When I make an html file and use  it outputs the image on the page, but when I try to echo the same attributes in php it just outputs a blank image and doesn't display the google captcha image. I am trying to create a forum login page for vbulletin but in this case it should use the captcha implementation since I don't want to sign up for crawling with bots on the my page by google. Can anyone tell me how I can go about doing this?

So basically after the request is made to obtain the key from the image which is assigned to $key the echo request doesn't output the image:

```
$key = the data inside the GET parameter 'c' everytime the captcha is requested.
echo "<img src='www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=".$key."'/>";
```

Comment: Are you actually using a captcha library to generate the image?

Comment: No, I am just taking it from google recaptcha

Comment: So you're doing something similar to what is documented here?  https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/wiki/HowToSetUpRecaptcha

Comment: No. My question is how can I take this url http://goo.gl/XWyGjO and output it as an image on my page using echo '' because the project I am working on is in php.

Comment: Then you're trying to use recaptcha without signing up for recaptcha?

Comment: Exactly! The client that I am working for specifically asked me not to and instead just grab the image from their links. My question is given that I already grabbed it, how can I output it as an image?

Comment: You can't use recaptcha without signing up for it.  If you look at the documentation, you'll see that you have to provide an API key to generate a captcha image.  Each captcha image is generated only once; they aren't re-used.  If you don't provide an API key, you can't get an image in the first place, and since you can't re-use images, you won't get an image without signing up.

Comment: Try searching for "alternatives to captcha" or "free version recaptcha" or something like that to find a solution you can host yourself, or that you don't have to sign up for.

Comment: Well lets just say that I just want to output goo.gl/XWyGjO
How do I go about it? I know I can output it with plain html just by doing
<img src="goo.gl/XWyGjO"/> 
my question is how come this doesn't work in php?

Comment: If you view source, and see <img src="goo.gl/XWyGjO"/>, then it is working.  However, since you don't have an account with Recaptcha, nothing will show up because Google isn't going to give you an image without an account.

Comment: Well that wouldn't make sense - then how come it works in html pages but not on php?

Comment: PHP outputs HTML.  Your browser is what is accessing the image, not PHP.  Also, I'm assuming you got <img src="goo.gl/XWyGjO"/> from some recaptcha example on another website somewhere.  Well, that URL will only work ONE TIME.  You can't point another <img> tag to it and get another image.  To get a new image, you need to send a request to Google, using their API.  Read the documentation I sent, go to the PHP example.  See all that stuff you're not doing??  All of that is necessary to produce a recaptcha image.

Comment: Dude... can you give me an answer or not? My question is simply how can I display the image in php???? I ALREADY HAVE A WAY TO GET NEW CAPTCHAS EVERY REQUEST... my question is simple nothing more - HOW CAN I OUTPUT THE CATCHA IMAGE THAT I GET FROM MY REQUEST WITH PHP?

I know that php outputs html. I'm not an idiot, but if this is so then how can it doesn't output the image after `echo "<img src="goo.gl/XWyGjO"></img>";` ? It just displays a blank box

Comment: Edit your question to include the PHP code you're trying.  Also, browse to the page you're having trouble with, view source, and copy the HTML output for the `<img>` tag give you trouble.

Comment: I editted the question with the php code I tried. The $key variable gets the long key of the captcha link everytime it is requested. But it doesn't output it.

Comment: What does the HTML look like that your program is producing?

Comment: Also, as someone pointed out in an answer, you do need to include something like "http", "https", etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a image regardless of the file extension. It's the MIME type that matters.

The reason why the following won't work is because of no specified protocol.

```
<img src="goo.gl/XWyGjO"/>
```

Working:

```
<img src="//goo.gl/XWyGjO"/>
<img src="http://goo.gl/XWyGjO"/>
<img src="https://goo.gl/XWyGjO"/>
```

// = inherit the current protocol.

Comment: <img src='www.google.com... Specify the protocol. (add // in front off www) :) The image will then load if it exists.

Comment: The image doesn't load when I put the protocol. It actually doesn't matter anyways though when I take the key myself and put it inside the url manually the page loads.

Comment: As long as the key is valid the image WILL be displayed. Your $key variable is probably not a valid key, resulting in a 500 error.

Comment: No no, it's valid I checked it myself. When I view source on the page it appears like so `<img src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=03AHJ_Vusn2Vw6h2…WB-aK9ZaeOwHjS8bzj93In-nxvIv02ISLm0qVM3V6Qx_aFJ-M1rXfN8f8UWm"></img>`

but it just doesn't display the image... I don't know why

Comment: That's not a valid URL. This one is:
`<img src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=03AHJ_VutuhPpm5eTb7OR8cUfxmAB8btOOGuPuhNi_3dT7lRM4BV3uCAZoqF0dF7JaSP2g2X_kTOqvrtwC0kxqtovyjZ2psWdZbnBT7arZocEY8YYnXcqL1zGl5hkY7q3vFbQQzl_4bgIHdRgV5tKU1vJlnZOLYkwjzqTXNgXbmdxXGk2ps_SAgRVYMY7n1mnsT9q_uSlP13-R"/>` Replace it and you'll see. Just use a link to a image and remember to specify the protocol and it will work, guaranteed.

Comment: -_- Dude are you serious? The '...' in the middle means that it supresses the string since its too long